# ViewData in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have 2 Cotrollers. 
First one sets the ViewData property like this
ViewData["Error"] = "something";
I am able display this message on the page.
Second Controller loads the grid.
When i try to set the ViewData property from that Cotroller, It does not show up on the page.

Do you why? Am I doing anything wrong here?

Please let me know.

Thanks!!!!

Comment: Pass the model back to the controller.

Comment: I am trying to display something on the page from the Grid Controller. So I am setting something in ViewData so i can display that on the page. This is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using two controllers for a single view is a bit of a no-no.

Look into ViewModels to pass all of the required data to your view. You can then create a PartialView for your grid, and pass the necessary model to the Partial View as well. Consider ViewData / ViewBag a last resort when a ViewModel doesn't work.

Comment: Then why are you asking about two controllers?

Comment: This is what my whole page looks like.3 Text Boxes, 1 File Input, 1 Submit Btn, 1 Telerik Grid. User input values into the Text Boxes and Selects 1 File to be imported. Submit button takes these 4 things, reads the file and calls the WCF Service with 4 Parameters. (TXT1, TXT2,TXT3, FILDATA). WCF Returns an XML File. I save that on disk temporary location. This is all happening in 1 Controller event. Now the Grid Event is called and it parse the file and display the result in the grid. Here i want to put some value in the ViewData and want to display that message on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use two separate controllers to render the same view? If so you should probably consider, breaking the view logic of your "grid" into a partial view that you in turn render within your primary view.

As you mentioned "ViewData" twice, another item for consideration is the implementation of the  `ViewModel Pattern`. The Viewdata dictionary approach is fast and fairly easy to implement. however, it is not type-safe and errors due to typo's will not be caught at compile time.